# show only specific products based on categoty from xml with php

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am loading an .xml file and transform it to my needs. Everything so far works great.
In this xml there is a master product category and the sub category and also this xml has various products for e.g: clothes for men for children etc.

Is there any possibility to get only the results of a specific sub category?

Here is my Code:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: text/xml'); ?>
<?php
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>"; 
?>

<?
// specify url of xml file
$url = "xml_feeds.xml";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

echo '<PRODUCTS>';
// loop begins
foreach($xml->PRODUCT as $PRODUCT)
{

$input = $PRODUCT->CATEGORY_NAME;
list($a, $b) = explode(' » ', $input); //i am split the CATEGORY_NAME coz contains and the sub category.

$my_title = $PRODUCT->NAME;
$title = trim($my_title);
$description = $PRODUCT->DESCRIPTION;
$mastercat = $a;
$subcat = $b;
$manufacturer = $PRODUCT->MANUFACTURER;
$price = $PRODUCT->PRICE_WITH_VAT;
$url = $PRODUCT->PRODUCT_URL;
$imageurl = $PRODUCT->IMAGE_URL;

echo '
<PRODUCT>
<ID><![CDATA['.$PRODUCT->ID.']]></ID>
<NAME><![CDATA['.$my_title.']]></NAME>
<DESCRIPTION><![CDATA['.$description.']]></DESCRIPTION>
<CATEGORY_NAME><![CDATA['.$mastercat.']]></CATEGORY_NAME>
<SUB_CATEGORY_NAME><![CDATA['.$subcat.']]></SUB_CATEGORY_NAME>
<MANUFACTURER><![CDATA['.$manufacturer.']]></MANUFACTURER>
<PREVIOUS_PRICE_WITH_VAT><![CDATA['.$price.']]></PREVIOUS_PRICE_WITH_VAT>
<PRICE_WITH_VAT><![CDATA['.$price.']]></PRICE_WITH_VAT>
<PRODUCT_URL><![CDATA['.$url.']]></PRODUCT_URL>
<IMAGE_URL><![CDATA['.$imageurl.']]></IMAGE_URL>
<THUMBNAIL_URL><![CDATA[]]></THUMBNAIL_URL>
</PRODUCT>';

}
// loop ends

echo '</PRODUCTS>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved,

Before echo the xml i puted:

```
if ($b == "The Sub Cat to Display"){

echo '
<PRODUCT>
<ID><![CDATA['.$PRODUCT->ID.']]></ID>
<NAME><![CDATA['.$my_title.']]></NAME>
<DESCRIPTION><![CDATA['.$description.']]></DESCRIPTION>
<CATEGORY_NAME><![CDATA['.$mastercat.']]></CATEGORY_NAME>
<SUB_CATEGORY_NAME><![CDATA['.$subcat.']]></SUB_CATEGORY_NAME>
<MANUFACTURER><![CDATA['.$manufacturer.']]></MANUFACTURER>
<PREVIOUS_PRICE_WITH_VAT><![CDATA['.$price.']]></PREVIOUS_PRICE_WITH_VAT>
<PRICE_WITH_VAT><![CDATA['.$price.']]></PRICE_WITH_VAT>
<PRODUCT_URL><![CDATA['.$url.']]></PRODUCT_URL>
<IMAGE_URL><![CDATA['.$imageurl.']]></IMAGE_URL>
<THUMBNAIL_URL><![CDATA[]]></THUMBNAIL_URL>
</PRODUCT>';


}
```